# Is there a way to use HibernateTemplate/JPATemplate while writing Java Migrations in Flyway?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, flyway

I am working on a project using hibernate3 with annotation configuration, and was looking at flyway for database migration tasks synced with development. I was hoping to use HibernateTemplate in java migrations, however it looks like only JdbcTemplate is supported for writing migrations in flyway. Is there a way to use HibernateTemplate, or JPATemplate, rather than JdbcTemplate in Flyway Java Migrations ?

Answer (score 1):

Using HibernateTemplate or JpaTemplate **doesn't make sense** in this case. Flyway is responsible for changing the very fundaments (the actual DB structure) Hibernate is based upon. Hibernate then relies on the new post-migration DB structure being in place.

**Flyway** should therefore **run before** instantiation of the **hibernate session factory**.

Comment: It makes sense for data conversion steps when the underlying database structure is in place. The conversion might be easier to write using a JPA model. A second reason could be when envers auditing is used and you want to manipulate the data and keep the envers auditing information intact.